# Use Codeigniter Controller/Method approach for jQuery Uploadify

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, plugins, file-upload, uploadify

Does some body knows how to use Codeigniter Controller/Method approach with jQuery Uploadify plugin.

Traditionally (without Codeigniter), we use this JS code to upload the file (using Uploadify version 3):

```
$(function(){
    $('#upload-input').uploadify({
        'swf':         'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader':    'uploadify.php'
    });
});
```

But in my case, I would like the `uploader` file to be a method (ex: **upload**) of a class (ex: **profile**), where this method performs the file upload (in my case, an image) in the same way we did with `uploadify.php`.

I tried this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#upload-input').uploadify({
        'swf':         'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader':    '<?= base_url() ?>profile/upload/'
    });
});
```

This shows me a `HTTP Error (500)` by Uploadify box.

Any idea?

My final aim is to perform some GD tasks inside that method, like image resizing, and database updates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the POST method on the server side and have enabled CSRF protection, you may return the error 500. If that is true you would have to pass the value of csrf_token.